# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ReflectionUtil

Tags: spring-boot, log4j, build.gradle, slf4j, corda

I am using following version of corda -

```
buildscript {
    ext.corda_release_version = '2.0.0'
    ext.corda_gradle_plugins_version = '1.0.0'
```

I am using following version of spring boot web server -

```
buildscript {
    ext.spring_boot_version = '1.5.7.RELEASE'
    ext.spring_version = '4.3.11.RELEASE'
}
```

I am using following version of log4j -

```
dependencies {

compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:2.7"
```

Following error is thrown while compiling -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ReflectionUtil
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:273)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:179)
        at net.corda.server.ServerKt.main(Server.kt:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ReflectionUtil
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 9 more
```

Expecting insights.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a version of log4j that is conflicting with Springs own dependency on the library. Try removing your log4j dependency and rely on the one Spring is bringing in.

The log4j dep is probably a lower version than what spring wants, hence the NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: Yes I was using a conflicting version of log4j. 
I had not updated corda version number property"ext.corda_release_version" from "1" to "2" in build.gradle of cordapp folder. I had updated only in build.gradle of root folder. 
Due to this, Corda v1 too got downloaded along with Corda v2 and this resulted in downloading of two versions of log4j.